# How to reset TextField value in useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, input, textfield

I have a situation where I control my component with a state, so everytime I can click on an item and switch what's inside my component, but here's the thing,
In one of my Textfield in my component,I set defaultValue to state.note,so I can see the value in state,like below,

```js
const Rightbar: React.FC<rightbarProps> = ({ currentTodoId }) => {
  // global state management
  const todos  = useSelector((state:RootState)=>
    state.todo.todos.filter((todo=>todo.id === currentTodoId))
    );
  const currentTodo = todos[0]
//......some code

 <TextField
          id="noteTodo"
          label="Note"
          onBlur={()=>updateTodoNote()}
          onKeyPress={(e)=>keypressUpdateTodoNote(e)}
          multiline={true}
          defaultValue={currentTodo?.note ? currentTodo.note : ""}
          inputRef ={noteRef}
          size="medium"
          className={classes.remember}
          variant="outlined"
          rows={5}
        />
```

so everything works fine. but If I changed something in textfield ,which will trigger my redux dispatch and change state, That's what I intended to do, and after that, when I  tried to change the state by clicking another item , textField will still be the last thing I typed instead "" in default value ,I think it's because when I typed something , I set the value of textfield, and it would override defaultValue , so even I switch state, it would still be the same thing .

so do  anyone know how to handle the situation?
and like my question , right now my solution is to change Textfield value to null everytime I switch state (useEffect) , so It would display defaultValue. but I don't know how to  do that

Comment: based on what value we should decide that we need to reset the text field ?

Comment: @Shyam So what I want to do is when user click different item , it would show information on my components according to diffent state, so textField is supposed to different and show different text to user , but right now when I changed it , it will set value and override what's in default value , that's why I want to reset the value of text field

Answer (score 0):

There are few solutions to do that:

1. If you have the state of your swithch, then you can pass it as a dependency to useEffect, which will do your logic every time you click on a switch.

In this case you will have to add a single useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   currentTodo?.note = ''; // or call your function to reset the value you need
}, [ nameOfYourSwitchVariable ])
```

2. If a switch value is not reachable, then just create a useEffect to change the value of your note to '', and fire it only on mount.

```
useEffect(() => {
       currentTodo?.note = ''; // or call your function to reset the value you need
    }, [ nameOfYourSwitchVariable ])
```

As an addition, you can use `||` operator instead of ternary for defaultValue in your TextField component

```
<TextField
  ...
  defaultValue={currentTodo?.note || ''}
  ....
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but this does'nt work ,since I think the problem is textField's value was set when I changed what's inside textField, and when I switch to another state, the textField's value will still be the same and it will overrite whatever is inside defaultvalue. so I don't think changing currentTodo is the answer.